# Removing DIV Element before adding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an transparent DIV that contains some route information. This DIV should get displayed whenever the user clicks a "show route button". The DIV is adding just fine, butwhen the user clicks this button again (on another marker) another DIV shows up.

This is my code so far which works, up untill the removal. I feel it has something to do with a) the selector not matching, but when I inspect the DOM in Firebug, there clearly is a DIV with that id

```
function displayRouteInfo(duration, distance){
    removeInfoWindow(function(){
        // TODO: remove overlay again
        routeInfoWindow = jQuery('<div id="routeInfoWindow" style="color:white;"> <p><span style="margin:10px;"> Routeinformation <span style="margin:10px;"> Dauer: '
                    +duration+'<span style="margin:10px;"> Entfernung: '+distance+'</p> </span></div>');
        routeInfoWindow.appendTo(document.body);
        }
    );
}


function removeInfoWindow(callback){
    $('routeInfoWindow').remove();
    callback.call();
}
```

Thanks for any input and advice to solve this.

Comment: triple check `$('routeInfoWindow').remove();` should not be '#routeInfoWindow'.  want to add some html for us to ensure solution accuracy?

Comment: undefined was right, I simply dropped the #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not correct, you have missed the `#` for ID selector.

```
$('#routeInfoWindow').remove();
```